# Querying while eager loading in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, eager-loading

I have a `News` Model which has polymorphic association with `ContentRoles`

I want to query news on created_at such that it fetches all the news greater than given timestamp

my query currently looks something like this

```
 @news = News.includes(:content_roles).where("created_at >= ?",params[:created_at] ,content_roles: {role_id: @role,content_type: "news"})
```

which is incorrect as it expects only one parameter for the prepared statement.

how do I  query on news created_at with conditions ?

Comment: `News.includes(:content_roles).where("created_at >= ?",created_at)`, though why are you including content_roles, shouldnt it just be `News.where("created_at >= ?",created_at)`

Comment: because I need to fetch it for a specific role

Comment: ok so what should the content role be equal to ?

Comment: I need only those news and content where content_role.role == admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `where` several times, and they will be chained with an AND:

```
@news = News.includes(:content_roles).where("created_at >= ?",params[:created_at]).where(content_roles: {role_id: @role,content_type: "news"})
```